# Protobuf-net: Is it possible to peek a single field by index without knowing the type?

Tags: protobuf-net

Assuming I receive a binary stream that I can guarantee is proto-buf serialized and that for every message we serialize, ProtoMember(1) is the (long) Id, is there a way to extract just that one field if I don't care about the type or the rest of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is one field and you know it is a `long`: cheat. Deserialize something that *only has that*. The library won't care about member names or type names - neither exist on the wire.

If it is in existing objects: implement an interface.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of just serializing an object with just the id... that will work since the index is always the same.